# Jquery trigger problems

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jquery's trigger function to simulate a click on a personal google Australian search page that I'm developing. From what I've read you can use trigger to just simulate a click on a link but I seem to be having problems and google seems to be very stingy with its info. Here's the code:

```
<a class="link" href="<?php if(isset($newurl)) { echo $newurl; }?>" target="_blank">tab link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("a .link").trigger('click');
</script>
```

Thanks very much!
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `trigger` method will fire the `click` event, but the `click` event will not cause the default behaviour of the link. It will only cause any associated `click` event handlers to be executed.

I'm not sure if you have a `click` event handler bound to the link that you haven't shown, but I'm just assuming what you're trying to do is follow the link.

If that is what you're trying to do, you can bind an event handler to the link and redirect the user in there. For example:

```
$("a.link").click(function() {
    window.location = "somewhere.html";
});
```

Comment: How do I go about adding event handlers to the link?

Comment: @killkrazy - I've updated my answer. You can use the jQuery `click` method to bind a click event handler to an element.

Comment: Good suggestion but I'm trying to get the href to pop up in a tab in google chrome and I thought I could get round the default behaviour of google. Google chrome doesn't allow window.open("http://localhost/123", '_blank'); unless it's in a 'actual click event'.

Answer (score 3):

```
  $("a.link").trigger('click'); ( without space)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a space between `a` and `.link`; remove it and you should be OK. (`a.link` means find the `<a>` tag with class `link`, while `a .link` means find elements with class `link` inside `<a>` tags).